# What does this dollar sign mean in __asm?

Tags: c, assembly

I tried googling this and I couldn't find anything informative enough for my understanding.

```
int i;
char msg1[] = "odd";
char msg2[] = "even";
char *ptr;
__asm__("                   \
    movl i, %eax\n\
        andl $1, %eax\n\
        jz  zero\n\
        movl $msg1, %eax\n\
        jmp done\n\
zero:\n\
        movl $msg2, %eax\n\
done:\n\
        movl %eax, ptr\n\
  ");
```

Why does some need `$` and the other (such as i) not have a `$` sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is constant one

```
 `andl $1, %eax` this means do  AND of 1 and EAX register.
```

`$` is prefixed infront of contants and immediate valued.
msg1 and msg1 are addresses of the two arrays. So they are too prefixed with `$`.

`i` is a c variable. Which is accessed using a `memory access` (Indirect reference).

Check this [reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Prefixes).

Comment: `msg1` is also a C variable. Why does it have a dollar sign?

Comment: msg1 is a label and $msg1 gives the address of that memory location.

Answer (score 1):

`Constants`need to be prefixed with a `"$"`.

```
movl $msg1, %eax\n\
```

The dollar sign meant a constant, and the same is true for `$msg1`. The constant here is the address of `msg1`.

Comment: You are talking about intel syntax. Above is AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 0):

$ here is same as & in C/C++ meaning address-of